# Add existing class to mfc application

Tags: c++, class, mfc, include

I try to ad an existing class to an SDI MFC application by right click on project, add existing item and after finding the class clicking OK. However, when I try to include this file by #include "Employer.h" the #include is by red color underlined and I get the message:
"Cannot open source file". Do I omit something that causes this problem? When I remove the class and try to create a new one and copy-paste the existing code I receice the message: "Object Employer already exists". What should I do to add an existing class to an MFC application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `Employer.h` is in project directory, or in one of "additional include files" directories.

Comment: That's it. The files are not automatically added to the project directory. I have to do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

Add the full path to Employer.h in your #include statement or add the parent folder of that file to the (-I?) include directories of your IDE.